# Getting the following error message TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to read a circle with its coordinates and radius from the user and trying to return its details but on executing this code i am getting an error.

```
import math
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, centre, radius):
        self.centre = centre
        self.radius = radius
        self.area1=math.pi*radius*radius

    def __str__(self):
        return ("A Circle which has centre at " + "(" + "%0.6f" % (self.centre)+")" + "and its radius " + "%0.6f" % (self.radius))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("CHECKING THE FUNCTIONALITY OF CIRCLE CLASS")
    x = float(input("Enter x coordinate of first circle's centre: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y coordinate of the first circle's centre: "))
    r = float(input("Enter first circle's radius: "))
    pointx1 = x
    pointy1 = y
    radius1 = r
    centre_1 = (pointx1,pointy1)
    first_circle = Circle(centre_1, r)
    print(first_circle)
```

Error message says:

```
File "C:/Users/Deepak/Desktop/part2.py", line 9, in __str__
return ("A Circle which has centre at " + "(" + "%0.6f" % (self.centre)+")" 
+ "and its radius " + "%0.6f" % (self.radius))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I can't understand what went wrong here.I need help urgently.Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to first assemble the whole format string and then pass all the data via one % operator.

Comment: Tried that many times but to no avail

Comment: Hm. In `self.centre`, you have a tuple. That seems to be incompatible with the float format string. Try splitting that up like `"(%0.6f, %0.6f)" % self.centre`.

Comment: That works.Thank you so much